# SQL select count from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, distinct

I'm a starter at SQL and I have the following tables, `ORDER_PRODUCTS`, listing the products of an order and `EXCHANGE_PRODUCTS`, listing products that will be exchanged.

Both have the same fields, and I need to make a selection counting the `amount` of products in both tables, distinguishing them by the `order_id`, does anyone knows how I can do this?

ORDER_PRODUCTS

```
+-----+------------+----------+---------+
|  id | product_id | order_id | amount  |
+-----+------------+----------+---------+
|   1 |          5 |        1 |       2 |
|   2 |          7 |        1 |       1 |
|   3 |         13 |        5 |       1 |
|   4 |         18 |        8 |       3 |
|   5 |         45 |       11 |       4 |
+-----+------------+----------+---------+
```

EXCHANGE_PRODUCTS

```
+-----+------------+----------+---------+
|  id | product_id | order_id | amount  |
+-----+------------+----------+---------+
|   1 |          5 |        1 |       1 |
|   2 |          7 |        1 |       2 |
|   3 |         13 |        5 |       1 |
|   4 |          3 |        8 |       2 |
|   5 |          2 |       11 |       1 |
+-----+------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Where is your query that you have tried?

Comment: please provide a sample with expected result ..

Comment: Do You need sum of objects from Order and exchange? Or two different numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `union all` to combine the tables and then aggregate them.  I might recommend:

```
select order_id, sum(ordered) as ordered, sum(exchanged) as exchanged,
       sum(exchanged + ordered) as total
from ((select order_id, amount as ordered, 0 as exchanged
       from order_products
      ) union all
      (select order_id, 0 as ordered, amount as exchanged
       from exhange_products
      )
     ) oe
group by order_id;
```

It is important to use `union all` rather than `union`, because `union` removes duplicates (which can result in bad numbers).  `Union` also incurs overhead that is unnecessary.

And, by "count amount" I assume you really mean to take the sum.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it worked just as I needed. I will look more into these advanced statements, they are amazing!

Answer (score 3):

I think this query should do what you Need:

```
select sum(amount), order_id from (
     select amount,order_id from order_products 
     union 
     select amount,order_id from Exchange_products) 
group by order_id
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, if you use SUM, instead of COUNT and product_id instead of order_id. 

Count would count the rows instead of the values inside the amount column.

And I think he wants to know how many of a product has been order, not how many orders have been made.

Comment: @RubenPirotte Sorry my fault. have changed my answer

Comment: Still I think it should also be product_id everywhere instead of order_id.